# Change Objective Function in nls.lm() in "R"

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I'm using the function nls.lm {package: minpack.lm} to optimize a parameteristion for a hydrological model. The function is working quite well, but I want to use an other `objective function (OF)`. Normally, the obective function "fn" in the nls.lm is defined as

```
A function that returns a vector of residuals, the sum square of which 
is to be minimized. The first argument of fn must be par.
```

Now I want to use the `Nash-Sutcliff-Efficiency`, which is defined as

```
NSE <- 1 - (sum((obs - sim)^2) / sum((obs - mean(obs))^2))
```

or other OF. The problem is that `nls.lm` minimizes the expression `sum(x)^2` and only the `x` is modifiable. I know that the `best fit NSE = 1`. Thus `1 - NSE` creates a real minimization problem.

BTW: Example 1 from a `nls.lm` [help page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/minpack.lm/docs/nls.lm) is a good example; there

```
observed - getPred(p,xx)
```

is minimized, what actually means that

```
sum ( observed - getPred(p,xx) )^2
```

is minimized by the `nls.lm` function, whereas `getPred(p,xx)` returns `sim`.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.
Micha

Answer (score 1):

nls.lm (and the related functions nls, and nlsLM) are designed to minimize the sum square of the residuals.  For the problem you seek to solve, I would try application of a general-purpose minimizer.

If the problem is 'not too hard' (that is, has a single global minimum, is smooth), you could try to apply 'optim' to it (I would try the 'Nelder-Mead' and 'BFGS' options first), or the 'bobyqa' function from the package 'minqa', among other functions.

If the problem requires a global optimizer, you could try the 'GenSA' function from package 'GenSA', the 'genoud' function from the package 'rgenoud', or the 'DEoptim' function from package 'DEoptim', among other options.   A review on 'Global Optimization in R' is forthcoming in the Journal of Statistical Software, and that will give a more complete overview of applicable functions.

Comment: hmm, why the downvote? (the OP did say "any suggestion would be helpful" ...)